# Converting a String to a jsonArray

Tags: java, android, json

my String:

```
String bu =  "[{\"name\":\"Personal Care\",\"created_at\":\"2018-04-29T10:55:37+00:00\",\"id\":2},{\"name\":\"Domestic Appliances\",\"created_at\":\"2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00\",\"id\":3},{\"name\":\"Coffee\",\"created_at\":\"2017-11-08T20:46:14+00:00\",\"id\":4}]"
```

Method i am using to convert the string to JsonArray:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(bu);
Log.v("s" , jsonElement.getAsString());
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
```

Error i am getting in the  logs:

```
06-21 18:39:43.265 9128-9128/com.harit.abs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.harit.abs, PID: 9128
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
    at com.harit.abs.Sync_Activity$2.onCompleted(Sync_Activity.java:95)
    at com.harit.abs.Sync_Activity$2.onCompleted(Sync_Activity.java:80)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:107)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:141)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:128)
    at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:246)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:60)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Can confirm, works without any problems.

Comment: that is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Here you get JSONObject so change

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed);
```

line with following

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(readlocationFeed);
```

and after

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a JSONArray.... you can also try something like this... which is way simpler, in my opinion, of course.

Try this.

> String bu =  "[{\"name\":\"Personal
>   Care\",\"created_at\":\"2018-04-29T10:55:37+00:00\",\"id\":2},{\"name\":\"Domestic
>   Appliances\",\"created_at\":\"2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00\",\"id\":3},{\"name\":\"Coffee\",\"created_at\":\"2017-11-08T20:46:14+00:00\",\"id\":4}]";

```
try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(bu);
        System.out.println(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code above will print out the following:

> [{"name":"Personal
>   Care","created_at":"2018-04-29T10:55:37+00:00","id":2},{"name":"Domestic
>   Appliances","created_at":"2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00","id":3},{"name":"Coffee","created_at":"2017-11-08T20:46:14+00:00","id":4}]
>
> Personal Care
>
> Domestic
>
> Appliances
>
> Coffee

Comment: OP seems to use gson and not jackson